# H2O AutoML, custom nfolds and fold_column

Tags: h2o

When trying AutoML, with `nfolds = 3` and a specified `fold_column` I get an error:

`Cannot specify fold_column and a non-default nfolds value at the same time`

Anyone have a workaround?  Or am I stuck with the default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you see this error is that you are trying specify the folds in two different ways.  If you want randomly created folds, then you can use the `nfolds` argument and H2O will create the folds for you.

If you want custom folds (so that you have control over which observations go into which fold), then you can add a column to your training frame that contains fold indices.  Then you set `fold_column` equal to the name of that column.

You must choose one or the other (not both).

Comment: I was confusing `fold_column` with `fold_assignment`.  Oops.  Thanks for the quick feedback!

Comment: I was wrong on my understanding of both `fold_column` and `fold_assignment`: I was looking for a way to do the equivalent of *scikit learn* `GroupKFold` by specifying the column to group on.  Looks like you manually need to make a kfold column in the dataset that does the grouping.